# Are there any consequences to not running air conditioner in a hot and humid climate?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

The AC in my house has been broken for several weeks, during which time the temperatures have gotten into the 90s with high humidity (heat indices over 100 the last few days). Because the AC is broken, the house is not cooled / dehumdified, and I wonder what the effects of that increased temperature / moisture would be on the house itself, personal comfort aside?

I'd like answers to include effects on furniture but to keep it on topic, let's limit it to how the framing, walls, flooring, and appliances would be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any permanent damage to anything structural, or furniture or appliances.  Those may absorb some humidity, but will return to normal when the AC is fixed.  But I would worry about a mold bloom.  I would consider running a dehumidifier (which, unfortunately would add heat), or getting a portable AC unit that you duct out a window.

Comment: ...or for the mold bloom aspect, make sure to circulate air... i.e. run fans...  the way it happened before air conditioning existed.

Comment: I only see problems for the most part in the winter when folks turn the thermostats down from the 70's to just above freezing when going on vacation the huge temp swing cracks drywall tape joints I think it is worse because the humidity is very low in winter, I have not seen this so much in summer. + for mold Tyson.